# How to create array of objects from array: javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert an array of elements to an array of objects in Javascript (react)
Here is the data I am getting from my API

```
"versions": [
    "1.0.1.2",
    "1.0.22.0",
    "1.1.0.12",
    "2.5.2.6",
    "2.5.2.7",
    "2.7.5.11",
    "2.7.7.7",
    "3.9.2.94",
    "3.9.3",
    "5.2.0.87",
    "9.5.0.210" ]
```

And I am trying to convert to an array of object which should look like this

```
options = [
    { value: "1.0.1.2", label: "1.0.1.2" },
    { value: "1.0.22.0", label: "1.0.22.0" },
    { value: "2.5.2.6", label: "2.5.2.6" },
];
```

I tried using the map function

```
versions = VersionloginData.data.versions.map((version) => [version.value, version.label])
```

But didn't work out well , i am getting undefined as value objects

Comment: `map(version => ({ value: version, label: version })`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to return an object inside the map callback:

```js
versions = VersionloginData.data.versions.map((version) => ({ value: version, label: version }))
```

Comment: You saved my life , thank you , actually i tried this without the callback , like
versions = VersionloginData.data.versions.map((version) => { value: version, label: version })

Comment: @Naveen the code in your comment isn't valid. You need to put `()` around `{}` for an object to be returned

Comment: Got it , Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Its should be.

```js
const data = {
  "versions": [
    "1.0.1.2",
    "1.0.22.0",
    "1.1.0.12",
    "2.5.2.6",
    "2.5.2.7",
    "2.7.5.11",
    "2.7.7.7",
    "3.9.2.94",
    "3.9.3",
    "5.2.0.87",
    "9.5.0.210"]
}
const output = data.versions.map(item => ({ value: item, label: item }));
console.log(output);
```

**Why your code is not working?**

You are accessing incorrect nodes with `[version.value, version.label]`. `value` and `label` doesnot exist on `version`. Instead, you should return an object with keys `value` and `label` having same value.

Comment: Thank for the explanation

Comment: If this fixes your issue, please approve this answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var options = [] 
versions.forEach((v)=>{
  options.push({
    value: v,
    label: v,
   })
})
```